# How to store image in filesystem folder and its path in database?

Tags: mysql, database

So, a few days ago I talked with you about this issue. Basically, I have a MySQL database and I want to store image paths in it.

My database is this:

[image]

In the Image field there's a BLOB file but I don't to store BLOB files.

My question is: Where can I store the images? In htdocs? and how do I store the path in the database?

Thank you

Comment: A few days ago... what? Did you just copy some e-mail here? :-)

Comment: @LarsGendner no, I talked about this in a PHP chat

Comment: I want to save image in filesystem but without PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Your Backend that handle the upload image should save the image in a directory and save the url into yur database.

For example with NodeJS and Multer NPM you can save the file to a destination and when uploaded save the full path to your database instead of the buffer.